QGIS - workflows that allow barriers to be modelled for flooding/water flow?
So I've seen ArcGIS Pro 3.3 has a flood simulation tool which allows for the creation of barriers.
I'd prefer to use open-source GIS like QGIS, and was just wondering is there any way I could model flood simulation or water flow using a DEM which takes into account if a 5m barrier (for example) was in place?

Hec-Ras comes to mind:  https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-ras/ or Whitbox:  https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/geospatial-software/
